# arraycopy: element type mismatch: Can not cast java.lang.Object[] to java.lang.reflect.Array

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert the `ArrayList` password into a `String` array but I get this error:

> arraycopy: element type mismatch: Can not cast java.lang.Object[] to java.lang.reflect.Array

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int p = 0;
    System.out.print("How many characters do you want your password to be: ");
    int i = sc.nextInt();
    Array pass[] = new Array[i];
    while (p < i) {
        characterChooser();
        if (o == 1) {
            //System.out.println(password);
            Array[] temp;
            temp = password.toArray(new Array[password.size()]);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));
            pass[p] = temp[0];
            p++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html. You say you want a `String array` (which should be `String[]`) but you create an `Array[]` which is an array of class `Array`.

Comment: The `Array` class is part of the Java reflection package. It's not an `ArrayList`? I presume you're trying to make an array of something, strings for example? Regardless, an `ArrayList` and an array are completely different. Maybe take a look at the link @maloomeister provided and an overview on `List` types.